# I want to save the Dictionary Values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have something like this where I need to hold some values

```
static Dictionary<string, int> DICT1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> DICT2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

And I need to be able to store in DICT2 what's in DICT1 but the DICT1 values needs to be initialized from 0 every iteration

Let's say I do this

```
foreach (var v in words)
{
    string t="";
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        t = "first word"  //this is just for example 
        if (v == ArrayOfWords[i])
        {    
            DICT1[ArrayOfWords[i]] += 1;  
        }
    }
    DICT2.ADD(t,DICT1);
```

So now after the first iteration I have stored in DICT2 key t having the value DICT1.

If I reset DICT1 after some time in the DICT2 I wont have the values that I had when I added the pair(t,DICT1).

So all I'm trying to say is that dictionaries doesn't save a copy in the memory and if I modify the DICT1 i'm modifying everywhere I used DICT1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# works with references, so when you store DICT1 in DICT2 you are storing a reference, if you reset or change some values in DICT1 you will be changing values in DICT2.

To copy a dictionary use:

```
Dictionary<string, int> copy = new Dictionary<string, int>(DICT1); //--> temporal variable

DICT2.Add(t, copy);
```

Comment: I need to do this more than 2000 times so that means I'll need like a copy for each time I need it ?

Comment: I edited the method using the constructor of the dictionary to copy the content, I don't know about the performance of the copy process but this is the solution, you have to copy the content of the dictionary to avoid the reference.